# In what circumstances would a GetMsgProc functions would receive a code of less than 0?

Tags: windows, winapi

As the question asks, in what circumstances would the procedure supplied to SetWindowsHookEx with WH_GETMESSAGE as hook ID would receive a "code" parameter less than zero?

The help for the function states :

> If code is less than zero, the hook
>   procedure must pass the message to the
>   CallNextHookEx function without
>   further processing and should return
>   the value returned by CallNextHookEx.

For some reasons, I believe I'm receiving a message with a Code parameter of less than 0 when I would need to actually process the message.  Any insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those < 0 codes are [used internally](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/08/09/693280.aspx) to manage the list of hooks (Meaning you should always pass them along without looking at the data!)

See [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/08/10/694362.aspx) for details about how people abused the old version and why we now have the Ex versions...